# How to filter with the same value but different amount

Tags: sql, sql-server, filter, distinct-values

I have the same data on Account, Item, Project, Location, Date, and Version only differs in the Amount

| Account | Item | Project | Location | Date | Version | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Acc1 | 1001 | B1 | CA | 11/27/2022 | Actual | 100 |
| Acc1 | 1001 | B1 | CA | 11/27/2022 | Actual | 230 |
| Acc6 | 3001 | A1 | BA | 11/28/2022 | Actual | 70 |
| Acc6 | 3010 | A2 | AA | 11/29/2022 | Actual | 400 |
| Acc7 | 7001 | B2 | CD | 11/30/2022 | Actual | 620 |

[image]

I just want the data to be fetched from the same date as the Amount 230

How to filter it by query?

Please help thank you

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Why have you chosen the amount 230 ? which condition are you based on ?

Comment: Seems to me like a poorly designed table.

Comment: @DaleK, the shown expected result for Acc1 is just picking one row out of two. I don't see where there is a summing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GROUP BY and an AGGREGATE function to get your data. In example below I assumed you would like to have the highest Amount.

```
SELECT Account,
       Item,
       Project,
       Location,
       Date,
       Version,
       MAX(Amount) AS Amount 
FROM dbo.NotProvidedTableName
GROUP BY Account,
         Item,
         Project,
         Location,
         Date,
         Version
```

Answer (score -1):

Question is not really well defined. The only difference I see is you ignore the lower amount for the rest of that dataset is exactly the same? In such case group by the first 6 columns and take the max of the 7th column.

Comment: A useful comment maybe - but not an answer.